Determine whether a polynomial in a linear map is invertible
Suppose $V$ is a 93-dimensional $F$-vector space and $T:V\to V$ is linear. Suppose also that the minimal polynomial of $T$ is$$\mu _{T}=x^{4}-2x^{3}+5x+9.$$For $p=x^{3}+7x^{2}+11x-1$, is $p(A)=3T^{3}+7T^{2}+11T-1$ invertible? Though $F$ was not specified, I think it's safe to assume $F\in \{\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q}\}$, but I do not know whether this plays any role in the problem.
After thinking for a long time, long division is the best I could think of. This showed $\gcd (p,\mu _{T})=1$, so $p(T)$ is invertible (this I proved). However, this was a huge pain and I assume there must be a much better way (it was a homework problem and our professor does not usually assign numbing computation problems).
My question is, what is this method? More generally, for a linear map $S:V\to V$ and $q\in F[x]$, is there a general algorithm to determine whether $q(S)$ is invertible (other than doing long polynomial division)?
True things I did not find helpful (perhaps I failed to see things they imply): because $\mu _{T}(0)\ne 0$, $T$ is invertible (proved). Furthermore, since $\deg p<\deg \mu _{T}$, $p(T)\ne 0$ (by definition of the minimal polynomial).
Thank you very much for reading my question and any and all guidance you offer.

The answer to your general question is indeed that $q(S)$ is invertible iff $\gcd(q, m_S)=1$. Long division isn't that difficult. Annoying at first, but after a few times you get used to it. Actually, here you can just do it once. After the first long division you get the remainder $x(52x+105)$, which is a product of two linear polynomials. Since $x^3+7x^2+11x-1$ is clearly not divisible by any of the two factors (at least in characteristic $0$), they are coprime.
